# VB6 bug with number formatting?

Tags: vb6

I have yet to confirm this is an actual bug but at this point I'm starting to think it is. Our old product we still have support for has caused some issues with data. This product is built off of VB6. The issue in question is regional settings and number formatting.

There are two quick examples I can write out here that can be ran on your own computer that should validate this issue. Your regional settings need to be configured for Greece as well. Before running this.

```
public sub main ()
     dim sTwo as string, sThousand as string

     sTwo = "2.0"
     sThousand = "1,000"

     debug.print "should be 2.0 or 2"
     debug.print sTwo
     ' "2.0"
      debug.print clng(sTwo)
     ' 20
     debug.print cdbl(sTwo)
     ' 20
     debug.print format(sTwo)
     ' 20 

     debug.print "\nshould be 1000.0 or 1000"
     debug.print sThousand
     ' "1000"
     debug.print clng(sThousand)
     ' 1
     debug.print cdbl(sThousand)
     ' 1
     debug.print format(sThousand)
     ' 1
 end sub
```

Im just looking for some validation that this is actually occuring for other users and not just on my machine or coworkers with this machine.  However, if someone knows of a workaround for now that would be great. Im currently trying to look up how to force number formatting a certain way.

From Laneville's suggestions

```
?formatnumber("2.0", 1, vbUseDefault, vbFalse, vbTrue)
20,0
?formatnumber("2.0", 0, vbUseDefault, vbFalse, vbTrue)     
20
?formatnumber("2.0", 0, 0, vbFalse, vbTrue)
20
?formatnumber("2.0", 0, 0, vbFalse, vbfalse)
20
```

Comment: FYI, `format(sTwo)` makes no sense -- you have to pass a `Double` (or `Long`) not a `String` and `formatnumber("2.0", ...` makes even less sense -- again you need a `Double` that is going to be formatted. You have *two* separate issues here -- converting a string (probably from US locale or culture invariant) to a number and second one is formatting a number to current locale. Second one is easy -- just use `Format`/`FormatNumber` with `Double`s not `String`s! First one is going to become a kludge very quick.

Comment: Appreciate it. And ya the issue is the data comes in as a string and theres no way around that. We have other methods that just get an actual number. But for this instance it cant currently be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the VB6 Format$ function to convert a numeric type to a string for display to a user.  Keep numeric values as numbers internally, don't store them as string, that is the wrong datatype to hold numbers.

Assuming your number variables are storing the value you expect, Format$ should work for formatting for display.  It is stated to be locale aware.  Your code above is not specifying a format expression, take a look at what is available:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Here is a relevant excerpt:

(.)

Decimal placeholder. In some locales, a comma is used as the decimal separator. The decimal placeholder determines how many digits are displayed to the left and right of the decimal separator. If the format expression contains only number signs to the left of this symbol, numbers smaller than 1 begin with a decimal separator. To display a leading zero displayed with fractional numbers, use 0 as the first digit placeholder to the left of the decimal separator. T**he actual character used as a decimal placeholder in the formatted output depends on the Number Format recognized by your system.**

Comment: Thanks but the issue with this is the numbers are being parsed in from a webpage. So I cant bring them in as a number I need to format it before as a string to get it to be used as a number. And the system I am testing on is set to greece which is what I have the issue for. 

So forced to take a string value and convert. to number. Currently no way around that. And the format method and numberformat both wont ignore the greek settings.

Comment: But that is informative is someone is just checking this thread out

Comment: If you know that the source will always be set for "Greece", then you could probably write your own number parser pretty easily.  That way, you could completely control the parsing of the source.  Once parsed, you should store that number in the appropriately-typed numeric variable, then as @tcarvin mentioned, used the VB `Format()` function to get it back into a string.

Comment: I agree, this is not a Formatting issue as first stated, it is a Parsing issue.  A quick google search found this, see if it helps:  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?736407-VB6-VConvert-A-Class-for-Locale-Specific-Data-Conversions

Comment: Appreciate the link from tcarvin. As well as the mark for the possible solution. I might have to end up doing this because for whatever reason windows localization isnt working on the greece values properly. So i may have to may a function that properly handles this issue for this specific client. I was just hoping for an resolution that didnt involve a lot of refactoring haaha. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [FormatNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/formatnumber-function) function, you can specify the number of digits after decimal (1000.0 vs 1000) and if digits are to be grouped (1,000 vs 1000).

```
FormatNumber(1000, 0, vbUseDefault, vbFalse, vbFalse)
```

This returns 1000.

```
FormatNumber(1000, 0, vbUseDefault, vbFalse, vbTrue)
```

This returns 1,000.

Comment: While this is something along the lines I still am unable to get what I am after. Reading it over and trying it out further pushes the idea there is something not accounted for on microsofts end or user error on my end. 
I tried multiple methods of that i do want the second paramter as 0. But it seems that even setting everything else to false still converts "2.0" to 2 when using a greece based setup.

Comment: `FormatNumber(2, 1, vbUseDefault, vbFalse, vbTrue)` gives you 2?

Comment: A reminder. I have greece settings which things like format, CDbl, CInt etc. are suppose to be able to handle just fine. 
Greece uses "." to seperate groupings and "," to seperate decimal values